# Is the error C1083 cannot open compiler generated file 'somePath\someFile.cod" related to Whole Program Optimization?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

When I build I find I'm getting errors about missing cod files. The compiler seems to be trying to link to a lib that had some flag set when it was built to output .cod files.

I don't see why the cod files are needed though to link, shouldn't the lib be enough?

Thanks

Comment: That's novel.  Post the compile command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prevent .cod files from being produced by opening the project that produces the lib. Go to project settings, C++, Output Files, and switch assembler output off. (So that in the raw text of the vcproj file you get AssemblerOutput="0").

This appears to make the problem go away, but I'm still not sure why the linker was looking for .cod files in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

To enable creation of .cod/.asm files with assembly listings for some library, disable whole program optimization and link time code generation when building that library.

1) Project Properties - Configuration Properties - General - set "Whole Program Optimization" to "no whole program optimization"

2) c/c++ - optimization -  set "Whole Program Optimization" to  "No"

3) Librarian - set "Link time code generation" to "No"